# I want to make a loop of this code so that if the ord(message) entered is more than 124 it comes back to 0 and if the ord(message)

Tags: python

```
message = input("Enter a message: ")
list1 = []
for i in range(len(message)):
if ord(message[i])>124 then +3-127
list1.append(chr(ord(message[i])+3))
print("".join(list1))
```

I want to make a loop of this code so that if the ord(message) entered is more than 124 it comes back to 0 and if the ord(message) is less than 124 then the loop will break. How can I make this loop?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

What you asked for :

```py
message = "example : ~"
#                    ^ 126
result = "".join(
    chr(0) if ord_c > 124 else chr(ord_c + 3)
    for ord_c in map(ord, message)
)
print(message)
print(result)
```

```
example : ~
h{dpsoh#=#�
```

In the ASCII table, `h` is 3 after `e`, `{` is 3 after `x`, ...
And `0` is not a printable character, so you get tofu : `�`